# Trying to load base 64 image in nextjs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, image, next.js

I uploaded my image in this way and this method works, it uploads in a string:

```
             const [image, setImage] = useState("");
            //------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------------------------

            const handleImage = (e) => {
                console.log("Handle image called");
                const selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
                console.log("Selected file:", selectedFile);
                if (selectedFile) {
                    const reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = (e) => {
                        const imageData = e.target.result;
                        console.log("imageData: ", imageData);
                        setImage(imageData); // Store the Base64-encoded image data
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
                }
            };
```

And now in another file i have retrieved data from mongo which includes the image in what i think is base 64 and is a very long string. I am trying to render image like this but its not working only alt is showing:

```
                    const petCards = petData.map((pet, index) => (
                <div className="card-results-find" key={index}>
                    <div className="img-card-find">
                        <Image
                            src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${pet.image}`}
     //I have also tried {petData.image} for src
                            alt={pet.catName}
                            layout="fill"
                        />
                    </div>

                //css:

               .img-card-find {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                height: 90vh;
               }
```

the petData.image include something like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxIeJ.png)
**EDIT**
I uploaded the image like this:

```
const imageData = imageBase64.split(",")[1];
```

Comment: I don't see a question, only statements. It's not clear what you are asking. Which part of your code is not working and what is the problem?

Comment: The image part of code is not working where i use <Image /> it  is not rendering only alt is showing, i will update the question

Comment: Hmm, there are many possible reasons that the image might not be loading. The first step would be to console.log the full data/src string and paste it into your browser url bar to see if its is a valid image. If not, my guess is that maybe mongoose is treating binary data as text somewhere and that is corrupting the data. Make sure to save all image data in mongoose in a binary-friendly format, or consider storing the base64 itself as text in mongoose.

Comment: i tried to paste the  url in browser it said: Your client issued a request that was too large.
also i noticed while uploading the image to mongo i did this:
const imageBase64 = req.body.image; this is normal but i also did
   const imageData = imageBase64.split(",")[1];
do you think this might cause any problems?

Comment: I think the issue is that readAsDataUrl gives the whole data url including the "data: image/jpeg..." , and maybe you need `.split(",")[2]` because of a second comma? Maybe trimming spaces at the beginning and end is needed? Either way, if you can, i recommend renaming the field in your mongoose model to "imageSrc" and then just uploading the entire result of `readAsDataUrl`. This will perfectly preserve the mime-type information. Also I recommend storing the filename and extension in the mongodb as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the way you send data to backend by just sending the url:

```
                const handleImage = (e) => {
                console.log("Handle image called");
                const selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
                console.log("Selected file:", selectedFile);
                if (selectedFile) {
                    const reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = (e) => {
                        const imageData = e.target.result;
                        console.log("imageData: ", imageData);

                        const dataURL = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${btoa(imageData)}`;
                        console.log("dataURL: ", dataURL);

                        setImage(dataURL);
                    };
                    reader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
                }
            };
```

and in the server stop doing this:
const imageData = imageBase64.split(",")[1];
and encode the image:
const encodedImageData = encodeURIComponent(imageData);

this should store your image to db as a url

and when receiving the image:

```
        <Image
                            src={decodeURIComponent(pet.imageSrc)}
                            alt={pet.petName} 
                            width={300}
                            height={200}
                        />
```